# Sorting ArrayList in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

How i can ordenate the elements of this list in ascending order? I try collections.sort but i recieve
"The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List)"

```
    List <Municipio> ms = new ArrayList <Municipio>();

    String path = "C:\\LP\\Dados_IBGE.txt";
    File f = new File(path);
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(f);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(in.hasNextLine()){
        String Linha = in.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Linha, "*");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            Municipio m = new Municipio(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
            ms.add(m);
        }
    }
        System.out.println(ms);
}
```

}

Comment: your might be searching for `Collections.reverse`.

Comment: What is `Municipio`? I guess it doesn't implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Where is the `sort` call?

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(ms, new Comparator<Municipio>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Municipio mcOne, Municipio mcTwo) {
      return mcOne.getSortCriteria().compareTo(mcTwo.getSortCriteria());
   }
});
```

Where `getSortCriteria()` is a method that contains the sort criteria of your object. If you want to reverse the order, simply multiply the return value by `-1`:

```
      return mcOne.getSortCriteria().compareTo(mcTwo.getSortCriteria()) * -1;
```

Comment: to reverse a `Comparator` just reverse the comparison, `return mcTwo.getSortCriteria().compareTo(mcOne.getSortCriteria());`

Answer (score 2):

Either make `Municipio` implements interface `Comparable` or put custom comparator as second argument to method `sort`:

```
Collections.sort(ms, new Comparator<Municipio>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Municipio o1, final Municipio o2) {
            // TODO compare o1 and o2:
            // return 1; //if o1 > o2
            // return -1; //if o1 < o2
            // return 0; //if o1 == o2
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse your collection in this way:

```
Collections.sort(ms, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Municipio>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final Municipio o1, final Municipio o2) {
        // TODO compare o1 and o2:
        // return 1; //if o1 > o2
        // return -1; //if o1 < o2
        // return 0; //if o1 == o2
    }
}););
```

from javadoc

> **Collections.reverseOrder:** Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering
>   on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable interface...

Answer (score 0):

Please implement your Object `Municipio` with `Comparable` thats it.

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Municipio obj) {
       rerurn this.your_var - obj.your_var;
    }
```